# npm packages installed from command line not appearing in packages.json dependencies for React-Native project

Tags: npm, react-native

I have a React-Native project and I'm trying to install certain npm modules in my project.

However, when I try to do so from the command line, the packages says it is installed correctly, but it is not appearing in the `packages.json` dependency.

For instance, I installed `react-relay` using `npm install react-relay`.

The package looks to have installed correctly.  But I check my `packages.json` and `react-relay` is not in there.

I have tried `react-native link`, and the packages are not coming up.

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would need to use the "save" option: `npm install react-relay --save`

Comment: Still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `save` option

```
npm install react-relay --save
```

or

```
npm i react-relay --s
```

To remove node module from `package.json` file

```
npm uninstall react-relay --save
```

Here is [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for `npm install`